# Python multiprocessing works differently in the exe output

Tags: python, opencv, multiprocessing, exe

I have a project that plays video on the screen according to the data coming from the serial port using libraries such as pyqt5, opencv, multithreading, serial port. It works correctly on the IDE. When I get the exe output, it works differently. The working code is as follows:

```
process_name = "p" + sequence_no_str
process = multiprocessing.Process(target=play_function, args=(screen, sequence_no, active_status), name=process_name)
process.start()
self.process_listesi.append(process)  # İşlem nesnesini listeye ekleme
```

I used multithreading because I needed to play many videos at the same time.

The function that should work is as follows

```
def play_function(screen, sequence_no, active_status):
    print("Oynatma fonksiyonuna girdi")
    try:
        screen= int(screen)
        video = int(sequence_no)
        oynatma_durumu = int(active_status)
    except ValueError:
        print("Geçersiz girişler. Tüm değerler tamsayı olmalıdır.")
        return
        
    if screen< 1 or screen> 4:
        print("Geçersiz ekran numarası. 1 ile 4 arasında bir değer seçin.")
        return
        
    if video < 1 or video > 20:
        print("Geçersiz video numarası. 1 ile 8 arasında bir değer seçin.")
        return
        
    if oynatma_durumu == 1:
        # JSON dosyasını okuyun
        with open('config.json', 'r') as config_file:
            config_data = json.load(config_file)
            
        video_key = f"video{video}"  
        # Video yolu için config.json içindeki değeri alın
        video_name = config_data["videolar"][video_key]  
                
        # Video yolunu oluşturun
        video_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "videolar", video_name)
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
        fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))

        if not cap.isOpened():
            print(f"Video açılamadı: {video_path}")
            return
            
        cv2.namedWindow(f"screen{screen}", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
        cv2.setWindowProperty(f"screen{screen}", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)

        while True:
            ret, pencere = cap.read()
            if not ret:
                print(f"Video sona erdi: {video_path}")
                # Video sonuna geldiğinde başa dön
                cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)
                continue

            cv2.imshow(f"screen{screen}", pencere)
                
            # Videonun hızını ayarlamak için bekleme süresini hesaplayın
            wait_time = int(1000 / (fps*4))  # Milisaniye cinsinden bekleme süresi hesaplaması

            key = cv2.waitKey(wait_time)
            if key == ord('q'):
                break
            
        cap.release()
    elif oynatma_durumu == 0:
        print("video durduruldu")
        cv2.destroyWindow(f"screen{screen}")
```

Is the problem in the way I code or is there something I should pay attention to when buying exe. I would be very grateful if you help me.

Comment: If anyone is interested, I solved the problem.

in main.py for solution

if __name__ == "__main__":
freeze_support()
I added the "freeze_support()" code.